# When I run this code it output 40, not 39. Anyone know why?

Tags: c++

In the following code when I run it the output is `40` not `39` in the fourth line, shouldn't it be `39` as we return `j-1` not `j`?

```
int secret (int );
int another ();

double x = 10;
int const rate = 999; 

int main ()
{
   cout << " x first " << x << endl;
   x = 70;

   cout << "x second " << x << endl;
   int x = 80;

   cout << "x third " << x << endl;

   cout << secret (x) << endl;

   return 0;
} 

int secret (int x)  
{
   int i, j;
   i = x;

   if (i > 10)
       j = x / 2;
   else 
       j = x / 3;

   return (j-1), x/2;
}
```

Comment: Read about [the comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: Fourth line: int const rate. Is secret in different file? Or where is fourth line? Try to ask as precisely as you can.

Comment: @Lasoloz There are four lines of output. The fourth line is the fourth line of the output.

Comment: @hvd OK, I see it. My mistake.

Comment: This whole "program" could be reduced to `int main() {std::cout << (39, 40) << std::endl; return 0;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the last value in the comma expression is returned. That's `x/2 == 40`. `j-1` is [evaluated but discarded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Answer (score 0):

When there are two expressions in the form `e1,e2` the value after computation of e1 is discarded, so it is only useful only if e1 computation somehow alters the computation result of e2. Here `return (j-1),x/2` evaluates `(j-1)` (this does not have any effect on evaluation of `x/2`) and then evaluates `x/2` and returns it.

C++ functions can return only **one** element at anytime. If you were trying to return two values, one possible way is you create a `struct` containing the two values and you return the single `struct` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The secret function does the same as this version

```
int secret (int x)  
{
   return x/2;
}
```

The rest can be ignored.

This results in: 80 / 2 = 40